# How to refresh React Native WebView to initial url?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How does diffing props work for react natives virtual dom(whatever it is called, i.e. yoga)? What is the related source code for it?
It might be similar to updateDomProperties(https://holmeshe.me/understanding-react-js-source-code-virtual-dom-diff-VIII/)

Especially, i try to understand react native WebView (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) source property. Changing some fictive prop of source forces refreshing of webview for the same uri.

```js
source={{uri:"http://...", forceReload:this.state.forceReload}}
```

How is this possible especially for Android?

I want to learn this to make sure that this behaviour does not change and break refreshing feature of my webview.

Comment: By diffing, do you mean how the React/React Native component detect changes in props and re-render? If that is the case, you can look up for React component's life cycle, and shallow comparison used in React.

Comment: @blaz actually, i want to know how diffing props work in virtual dom or whatever they call it for react native.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually changing some fictive property on source causes virtual dom determine the change and call the setter of the source(setSource()) on the native webview.

But, native webview's setSource() checks uri and does not reload the url.

So, here is my way to refresh web view to initial url;

https://gist.github.com/expressiveco/d0063875ab15631199acc27abf633177

Comment: Yeah, I was also about to suggest to just have a button on the screen that allows the user to refresh the page or trigger it after an event/some time.